# can't install xp in virtualbox on ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-xp

I am trying to install winxp in virtual box, but was stopped here[image]

so, hope anyone who can help me figure out this problem! what can I do next?

Comment: You are trying to boot via pxe. Is this correct or did you just miss to add the Windows XP ISO as CD-Rom to your virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

You are booting From Network PXE. Just be sure that you already added your ISO to the CD controller, Go to settings -> storage -> CD/DVD Drive and coose your ISO.

Also be sure to make CD boot order is prior you can do it from settings -> System -> Boot order then uncheck Netwrok and Floppy and check CD/DVD and Hard Disk making CD as the first order

Comment: it doesn't work, do you believe that is there anything else maybe I didn't get right or the problem can be just solved in your way ?